# How do I get rid of the GREY brackets in Word 2021?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2021

How do I get rid of the GREY brackets in Word 2021?

Here is the founded answer on the net :

> Go to Word> Preferences - View to see if the box is checked for
> Bookmarks. If it is, clear the check & see whether the brackets
> continue to display when you close the Preferences window

But this is wrong - there is no Preferences and such that menu on word 2021.

How do I get rid of annoying brackets in Word 2021?

Comment: Can you go to File, Options, Advanced, scroll down to 'Show document content' then uncheck 'Show bookmarks' to see if it helps? This just seems to hide the bookmark/link rather than stop WHY its happening when you don't want it which is a bit more tricky

Comment: @gregg Thanks - Worked - Please put it as your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you go to File, Options, Advanced, scroll down to 'Show document content' then uncheck 'Show bookmarks' to see if it helps?

This just seems to hide the bookmark/link rather than stop WHY its happening when you don't want it which is a bit more tricky. Reading some forums people seem to have it happen when you copy & paste things from the web so Word COULD be trying to create a link automatically for you. In that case the fix is paste only the text by clicking arrow under Paste (else Paste Special is in that drop-down & can be triggered by Ctrl+Alt+V)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As someone who has struggled to find the answer to this question, here's sequence of directions if you're using a Mac:

Word > Preferences > View > Uncheck "Bookmarks"